# Identifying 1's in columns of sparse Matrix array C

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I am trying to get my program to identify how many 1's are in each column of the sparse matrix which the user input. I thought of using a nested `for` loop, an `if(p[i][j]=1)` and a counter `k++` but it prints a large amount of random numbers and then crashes. My whole code is included but the section where I am having trouble is `int **printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(int **p)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser();
int **printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(int **p);

int main()
{
int **p;
p = getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser();
printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(p);
return 0;
}

int ** getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser()
{
int atoi(const char *str);
int i;
int j;
int r, c, f, g;
int **p;
char str[20];
char term;

    printf("Please enter the number of rows:\n");
        scanf("%s", &str);

while(atoi(str)==0)
{
    printf("Invalid entry. \nPlease enter the number of rows:\n");
        scanf("%s",str);
}
    r = atoi(str);

    printf("Please enter the number of columns:\n");
        scanf("%s", &str);

while(atoi(str)==0)
{
    printf("Invalid entry. \nPlease enter the number of columns:\n");
        scanf("%s",str);
}
    c = atoi(str);

    p= malloc(r* sizeof(int*));

for (i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    p[i]= malloc(c* sizeof(int));
}

for(i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        p[i][j]=0;
    }
}

for (i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter the number of 1's in row %d :\n", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &f);


        if (f>0)
        {
            printf("Please enter column location of the 1's in row %d : \n", (i+1));

                for (j=0; j<f; j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d", &g);
                        p[i][g-1]= 1;
                }
        }
}
        printf("\nYou Have entered the Matrix!!!\n\nI mean this is the Matrix you have entered:\n\n");

    return p;
}
```

---

(everything above is just to help situate anyone that can help, this is where I am having trouble)

```
int **printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(int **p)
{
int i;
int j;
int c, r, k;

for(i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    printf("\t");

    for(j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

for(i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        if(p[i][j]==1)
       {
            printf("The number of 1’s in column %d is %d\n", (i+1), k);
            k++;
       }
    }
}



}
```

---

It works if I remove the part shown bellow, but I still need to identify the 1's in each column. I know the problem is here but I don't see why it crashes or why it wouldn't work.

```
for(i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<c; j++)
    {
        if(p[i][j]==1)
       {
            printf("The number of 1’s in column %d is %d\n", (i+1), k);
            k++;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: In `printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix`, `r` and `c` are not initialized.

Comment: Also, `if(p[i][j]=1)` should be `if (p[i][j] == 1)`. If you had put the `1` in the LHS, your compiler would have warned you. It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp im not sure what you mean, when you say I didn't initialize `r` and `c` and i do not know what LHS stands for, I am new to this.

Comment: In `printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix` what is the value of `r` in `for(i=0; i<r; i++)`? It is undefined. You declar `r'` in `int c, r, k;` but you don't give it an initial value.

Comment: LHS is _left hand side_. If you had typed `if (1 = p[i][j])` the compiler would have warned you that you can't assign a value to `1`. It's just a little habit I got into years ago that has helped more than a few times.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so the value of `r` and `c` won't be passed down from `int ** getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser()` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks for the tip I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: No! With `int c, r, k;` you create _local_ variables called c, r, k. These variables only exist inside that function. These are completely separate from the `r` and `c` in `getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser`. Google "C Variable Scope".

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but I still can't see how I could fix my original problem @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if I changed `printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(p)` and the prototype to `printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(p, r, c)` would it then carry the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `r` and `c` in `main()` and pass them to other funcs. Once by reference, once by value:

```
int main()
{
    int **p;
    int r, c;
    p = getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser(&r, &c);
    printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(p, r, c);
    return 0;
}

int ** getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser(int *r, int *c)
{
    // int r, c;    <- Remove
    ...
}
```

Since you now pass `r` and `c` as pointers, you have to deference them with pointer notation:

```
*r = atoi(str);
```

Then...

```
void printColumnStatisticsOfMatrix(int **p, int r, int c)
{
     // int r, c;    <- Remove
     ...
}
```

Lastly, you want to find the # of 1's in each column.

```
// Reverse your indices (and use better variable names)
for (int column = 0; column < c; column++)
{
    k = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        if (p[row][column] == 1)
            k++;
    }
    // This goes here
    printf("The number of 1’s in column %d is %d\n", (column + 1), k);
}
```

Comment: after I changed the `r` and `c` as you said and now I get en error `p= malloc(r* sizeof(int*));` and `p[i]= malloc(c* sizeof(int));` and multiple warnings when I compile.

Comment: Everywhere in `getBinarySparseMatrixFromUser` that you have `r` or `c` you need to change to `*r` or `*c` because in that function they are pointers,

Comment: thank you that worked but I still cant seem to get the program to identify where the 1's are located in each column

Comment: @Leo.p Updated the last loop.

Comment: i declare `row` and `column` as `int` correct i.e. `int row, column;`